# Using window manager other than GNOME in RHEL/CentOS

Tags: gnome, gnome3, window-manager

I am running centos 9, at home on a spare disk, test driving the latest version to see what it's all about.

Mention has been made, over the years, the default gnome window manager is not the best and there are better.

Can someone provide some simple instruction, and recommendation, for installing a replacement window manager for RHEL/CentOS ?  For either version 9, or 7.9... *I never ran version 8 and don't intend to fwiw.*

I use linux rarely at home, mostly in support for using linux at work which is my main interest...

is it worth it **in a work environment** to remove the GNOME window manager and use something else and if so what, and is it easily done or is it risky?

Comment: Do you want to change the *desktop environment* or the *window manager*?

Comment: "is it worth it in a work environment to remove the GNOME window manager?" Unless there's a *particular* window manager that you prefer and that you have experience with, doing this is mostly going to be a waste of time (or a "learning experience", if you prefer). Modern version of Gnome aren't that bad, and while there are some niche window managers with different functionality, none of them are "better"; it really depends on your own personal preferences.

Comment: *change the desktop environment or the window manager* - I don't think I know what the difference is between them... I just want to right click new terminal on the desktop, and have a basic start menu with icons

Comment: I want a *windows xp* type of user experience, no animation, no fancy stuff, plain and simple and reliable for work environment; at most change desktop background picture.

Comment: @ron Then I think XFCE will be right up your alley. No fancy stuff. I'll write an answer to your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
# update the repos
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh

# enable the crb
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled crb

# enable the epel-repos
sudo dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-next-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm

# check to see if xfce is available (or other desktop environments)
sudo dnf group list

# install xfce (de) with xorg (wm)
sudo dnf groupinstall "Xfce" "base-x"

# set the default
echo "exec /usr/bin/xfce4-session" >> $HOME/.xinitrc

sudo systemctl set-default graphical

# reboot for the changes to take effect
shutdown -r
```

Comment: will give it a try within next couple days when I can.  thanks.

Comment: @ron Please note that this is for Centos 9. You'll have to change the `epel` to the appropriate version of Centos for the repos to work.

Comment: if the extras respository is enabled you can probably just install the `epel-release` package directly rather than maybe using the wrong URL